# is there a way to mint from metaplex candymachine CLI to another wallet? or how to send multiple NFT's

Tags: metaplex, candy-machine

i have an NFT project, we have a promo ending soon which will involve me sending large amounts of NFT's to about 50 different holders wallets.

Is there a way i can mint multiple tokens from CLI using metaplex directly to another wallet??

or

Is there a way i can send a selection of NFT's (using a json Array) from the default solana wallet using my own custom RPC in CLI??

Example
I Mint 10 Tokens using metaplex and then send those 10 to another wallet.

Ive used a website to send multiple NFT's before but after a while i get timeout error as the default RPC has been over used.

Answer (score 1):

If you know javascript you can use the [Metaplex js-sdk](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js). This SDK has a function inside the `candyMachines()` module that allow you to mint from an existing Candy machine and specify a `newOwner` of the mint (you will mint an NFT and the NFT will appear on the `newOwner` wallet). This method is not documented yet, but it has a test that you can follow [here](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js/blob/main/packages/js/test/plugins/candyMachineModule/mintCandyMachine.test.ts#L126-L130)

Comment: Lol thanks but I have no idea what to do with that I don’t understand Java .. mark had said there was a solution but im not sure this was it. Thank you